# Command assoicated with a Check Box not firing in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox

I have an application that is build using MVVM in WPF. I have several check boxes within the grid. All of which are bound with a command. Now normally, when I use a mouse click to check/ uncheck a check box, the command fires appropriately. It works even when I use a space bar key press to check/ uncheck the check box. But, the problem arises when I use Add(+) or subtract (-) key on the keyboard for check and uncheck, respectively. Though,I am able to check/uncheck using + and - key but, the command is not fired.

Note: I have a boolean variable bound to the IsChecked property of the checkbox which does return me correct value even when I use + and - ,but even then the command is not fired.

Comment: can you please share the code.?

Comment: Wow, 26 years as a dev and I never knew you could use +/- to change a checkbox! Perhaps you could wire up a keyboard event to trap these keys, and execute the VM command. Not sure I'd bother handling an edge case that 99.9% of the population won't be aware of.